# What type of verbs take a clause as the direct object?

Tags: grammar, verbs, grammatical-object, transitivity

We have detailed *transitivity* classification for the valence and the number of objects a verb can take.

Some transitive verbs can take a complete sentence (a clause) as the direct object. For example,

> I *think* **he is ready**.

> I *believe* **he made it**.

> I *confirm* **he can do the job**.

> The report *shows* **he is capable of doing the task**.

There are, of course, some similar verbs taking the clause as an indirect object.

> She *told* me *that* **he is ready**.

Is there a linguistic classification (rather than simply listing them) for this type of verb?

Comment: Generally if a verb can take a complement clause as subject or object, it's characterized by which type of complement clause is involved (tensed _that_-clause, tensed embedded question, untensed participle/gerund, untensed infinitive), and what rules (Raising, Equi, _Tough_-movement, Extraposition, etc.) are required, optional, or forbidden with each. That's basically [a spreadsheet for every predicate](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf), intersecting with the syntax it's at the heart of. There are syntactic tests for all of them.

Comment: Excluding one special exception, objects of verbs consist exclusively of NPs, not clauses. In all your examples the expressions in bold are thus not objects but declarative content clauses functioning as complement of their respective italicised verbs. Not all verbs license such complement clauses, but I hesitate to define them in any meaningful way.

Comment: @jlawler, Your website is quite informative. The two cases of *participle/gerund* and *untensed infinitive* are classified under catenative verbs. However, I have not encountered any formal classification of verbs taking *that*-class or tensed embedded question.

Comment: @BillJ I agree that they are not objects per se, but some documents name them so. I am interested in the general property/classification of the verbs that can take complement clauses. What is their common feature? How can we identify them?

Comment: @Googlebot You can't, at least not reliably as far as I know. Some verbs license content clause complements while others don't.  I suspect it's a matter of familiarising yourself with the two types. It may help to try inserting the subordinator "that". If it works OK, than you probably have a complement clause.

Comment: @BillJ uses a different theory, with a different set of terminology, and presuppositions, than I do. So when he says  "thus not objects" or "consist exclusively of", he's talking about **his** terminology. You're free to use it if you like; I use my own terminology, which I've developed over 50 years of research. You're free to use that, too. BillJ and I agree to differ. Neither can enforce our decisions in any case.